# In order to mutually corresponding to multiple input at Mithril?

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

**default code**

・When the user input, display twice four times as a result of

```
   var Model = function () {
        this.num = m.prop(10);
    };
    var MyApp = {
        controller: function() {
          this.data = new Model('');
        },
        view: function(ctrl) {
            return m("div", [
                 "multiple1:",m("input", {oninput: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.data.num), value: ctrl.data.num()}),
                m("br"),
                m.component(NestComponent, {value: ctrl.data.num()}) //10
            ]);
        }
    };
    var NestComponent  = {
        controller: function() {
            return {
                multiple2: function(value) { //10
                    return (parseInt(value) * 2)
                },
                multiple4: function(value) { //10
                    return (parseInt(value) * 4)
                }
            }
        },
        view: function(ctrl, args) {
            return m('div', [
                "multiple2:", ctrl.multiple2(args.value),
                m("br"),
                "multiple4:", ctrl.multiple4(args.value),
            ]);
        }
    };
    m.mount(app, MyApp)
```

---

**The code does not work as intended**

・When the user enters in the top form, displaying the 1 times 2 times 4 times the results in order from the top.

・When the user inputs the center of the form, displaying the 1/2 times 1 times 2 times the results from the top.

・When the user enters in the form of the bottom, it displays the 1/4 times 1/2 times 1 times the results in order from the top.

```
var Model = function () {
    this.num1 = m.prop(10);
    this.num2 = m.prop(20);
    this.num4 = m.prop(40);
    // this.num2 = this.num1*2;
    // this.num4 = this.num1*4;
    // this.num2 = m.prop(10)*2;
};

var MyApp = {
    controller: function() {
      this.data = new Model('');
    },
    view: function(ctrl) {
        return m("div", [
             "multiple1:",m("input", {oninput: m.withAttr("value", ctrl.data.num1), value: ctrl.data.num1()}),
            m("br"),
            m.component(NestComponent, {val1: ctrl.data.num1(),val2: ctrl.data.num2(),val4: ctrl.data.num4(),mainCtrl: ctrl})
        ]);
    }
};
var NestComponent  = {
    controller: function() {
        return {
            multiple2: function(value) {
                console.log(value);
                return (parseInt(value) * 2)
            },
            multiple4: function(value) {
                return (parseInt(value) * 4)
            }
        }
    },
    view: function(ctrl, args) {
        return m('div', [
            "multiple2:", m("input", {oninput: m.withAttr("value", args.mainCtrl.data.num2()), value: args.val2}),
            m("br"),
            "multiple4:", m("input", {oninput: m.withAttr("value", args.mainCtrl.data.num4()), value: args.val4}),
        ]);
    }
};
m.mount(app, MyApp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second code snippet's inputs shouldn't be executing the props: `args.mainCtrl.data.num4()` shouldn't have the parentheses at the end.